# My Samsung Monitor keeps powering off... How can I fix this?

Tags: display

The PC is just fine, been runing okay for a few years. The monitor however, has issues. It is an odd issue that might be a sign of future broken monitor. For no apparent reason the monitor will just power off, so I have to manually turn it back on and it is fine. Is there something I can do to fix this besides the warranty? I already had it repair and I don't feel like shiping it again. I kind of want to just open it up, learn how to solder and well, you know the saying: If you want something done right then do it yourself.

Comment: None of these are acceptable answers, then again Samsung monitors aren't either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 1) the problem is 5 yrs old and has surely been overtaken by events, so there is no longer something to solve. 2) it cannot be solved based on the information available, and reasonable guesses have been unsuccessful and exhausted. 3) the evidence is that this is a unique problem specific to the OP's monitor. 4) hands-on repair has been unsuccessful so remote guesses at SU will not solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Does it really *power off* or go to standby?

- If it's standby then it could indicate a problem with the display signal, either from the computer or in the cable itself.
- if it actually switches off entirely then it is most likely a problem with the monitor's power supply.

  - If it's a TFT with an external power supply, then you could try to replace the power supply (but be careful to get one with a matching output!).
  - If it's a CRT, or a TFT with internal power supply, then it needs to be repaired or replaced.

Given the cost of new TFT monitors, I'd consider replacing the monitor.

Comment: Power off compleletly... I should have made this clear in the original question....

Comment: @Zombies: It sounds like a malfunction of the power supply, especially if it happens more and more often over the course of some months. Otherwise it could be a malfunction in the on/off circuitry. In either case, I'd replace the monitor (use the warranty if possible).

Answer (score 1):

The reasons I know, why monitors power off are:

- Cable problems: The green color usually has the sync frequency and if that is not arriving well, it may let some part of the monitor think it is out of sync. Check if all cable parts are OK by plugging them out and in again.
- Heat: It may be overheated and thus turns off. Especially the power supply section has such features. Reason could be dust (remove power cord and blow the dust out). If the place you use it has not enough air circulation (or sun shining on the monitor back), that could be the problem.
- Dust: Overheat in one of the areas due to not enough air circulation. Removing the dust can help
- Age Errors: Some Capacitors get bad over years and before finally dying the security feature is shutting it off. This would be a reason to be careful keeping it running

Answer (score 0):

Your capacitors could be bad, try powering on the monitor and turn the brightness all the way down to the lowest. If it stays on longer than it did before shutting down automatically it is the capacitors that need to be replaced. Since you say you have no problem opening it up, check the capacitors (be careful with this as these can give you a nice/nasty jolt as they store electrical charge), and probably look on Google and Youtube to see examples of bad capacitors, and while you're at it there are great tutorials on there on how to solder and replace that sort of stuff.

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem. What I found is that, inside the monitor -in the circuit board -you'll be able to see some capacitors,
 Take a tester and place it over the metal part of the capacitors this will Tell you whether they're good or damaged
And next thing try it over one of the resistors having multiple color code if you observe it
You see that  the monitor ons when the light in the tester ons. This says it's a problem in the board

Comment: Since no one else is saying it... Do not do this. Unless you are an electronics professional with proper safeguards, do NOT open a CRT monitor. You will likely be zapped, in a big way, if you are not careful

Comment: And where does one buy this magic tester that you just place over components and it tells you whether they are damaged?